# Updating only one instance of AppWidget

Tags: android, android-appwidget

I'm creating Android homescreen widget with clickable button. After clicking the button I'm updating TextView using data from SharedPreferences. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, but after clicking button each instances of widget are updated. How to update only clicked widget?

TestWidgetConfiguration:

```
public class TestWidgetConfiguration extends Activity {
    Button confirm;
    EditText edit;
    int mAppWidgetId = AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
        setContentView(R.layout.testwidgetconfiguration);

        confirm = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        confirm.setOnClickListener(confirmListener);

        edit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

        if(extras != null) {
            mAppWidgetId = extras.getInt(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID); 
        }

        if(mAppWidgetId == AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID) {
            finish();
        }
    }

    private Button.OnClickListener confirmListener = new Button.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent resultValue = new Intent();
            resultValue.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, mAppWidgetId);

            SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("prefs", 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.putInt("id:"+mAppWidgetId, Integer.parseInt(edit.getText().toString()));
            editor.commit();

            AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(TestWidgetConfiguration.this);
            TestWidget.updateAppWidget(TestWidgetConfiguration.this, appWidgetManager, mAppWidgetId);

            setResult(RESULT_OK, resultValue);
            finish();
        }
    };
}
```

TestWidget:

```
public class TestWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {
    public static String ACTION = "TestAction";
    public static String URI_SCHEME ="ASD";

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);

        Toast.makeText(context, "onUpdate()", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int appWidgetId) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("prefs", 0);
        int id = prefs.getInt("id:"+appWidgetId, 0);

        RemoteViews updateViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.testwidget);
        updateViews.setTextViewText(R.id.textView2, "[" + String.valueOf(appWidgetId) + "]" + id);

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, TestWidget.class);
        intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
        intent.setAction(ACTION);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, appWidgetId, intent, 0);
        //Uri data = Uri.withAppendedPath(
        //      Uri.parse(URI_SCHEME + "://widget/id/")
        //      ,String.valueOf(appWidgetId));
        //intent.setData(data);

        updateViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button1, pendingIntent);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, updateViews);

        Toast.makeText(context, "updateAppWidget(): " + String.valueOf(appWidgetId) + "\n", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onReceive(context, intent);

        Toast.makeText(context, "onReceive()", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        if (ACTION.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            int idd = 0;
            Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

            if(extras != null) {
                idd = extras.getInt(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID); 
            }

            Toast.makeText(context, "id: " + idd, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("prefs", 0);
            int id = prefs.getInt("id:"+idd, 0);

            RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.testwidget);
            rv.setTextViewText(R.id.textView1, "lala" + id);

            ComponentName testWidget = new ComponentName(context, TestWidget.class);
            AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
            manager.updateAppWidget(testWidget, rv);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: NVM...

Solution:

    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if(extras != null) {
        idd = extras.getInt(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID); 
    }
    ...
    manager.updateAppWidget(testWidget, rv); ===> manager.updateAppWidget(id, rv);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras(); 
if(extras != null) { 
    idd = extras.getInt(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID); 
} 

... 

manager.updateAppWidget(id, rv); // change
```

Answer (score 0):

In `TestWidget#onReceive` change the following line:

```
manager.updateAppWidget(testWidget, rv);
```

to

```
manager.updateAppWidget(idd, rv);
```

It is **idd** not id as Ziem wrote in the comment.